# Pfx файл. Подпись документа

Tags: openssl, цифровая-подпись

У меня есть Pfx файл(размер 7КВ): 22112018.pfx, в котором у меня ключевая пара и сертификат выданный УЦ.

Ключевая пара и сертификат находились на токене, откуда я их экспортировал в pfx файл, на картинке показана выбранная мной конфигурация экспорта + отметил все пункты:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне необходимо c помощью pfx файла подписать документ, для этого я pfx файл конвертирую в pem файл, командой:

> openssl pkcs12 -in 22112018.pfx -nocerts -out my_Pkey.pem -nodes

Но вылезает ошибка

> Error outputting keys and certificates
>
> 073742524:error:06074079:digital envelope
>   routines:EVP_PBE_CipherInit:unknown pbe
>   algorithm:evp_pbe.c:162:TYPE=1.2.840.113549.1.12.1.80
>
> 3073742524:error:23077073:PKCS12 routines:PKCS12_pbe_crypt:pkcs12
>   algor cipherinit error:p12_decr.c:87: 
>   3073742524:error:2306A075:PKCS12
>   routines:PKCS12_item_decrypt_d2i:pkcs12 pbe crypt
>   error:p12_decr.c:139:

Команда для подписи, была найдена до меня и работает 100%, нужно только нормальный pem файл

openssl smime -sign -signer *.pem -nodetach -binary -noattr -outform DER -in fileToSign -out

Comment: Ваш `openssl` не знает о OID `1.2.840.113549.1.12.1.80`. Я так понимаю это какой-то `ГОСТ`.

Comment: New version of P12FromGostCSP:
https://www105.zippyshare.com/v/0cZxZR8r/file.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

см. https://www.cryptopro.ru/forum2/default.aspx?g=posts&t=8944
1. Нужно инсталлировать сертификат (и ключи в систему)
2. Используя программу P12FromGostCSP, выгрузить сертификат и ключи
затем затем openssl pkcs12 -in p12.pfx -out p12.pem - ну или что хотите получить с помощью openssl